# Preg replace etting error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I am getting error wit preg replace.

Here is my code

```
$search='+5DR';
$replace='5';
$tempString='1.2 EASY +5DR';
echo $tempString = preg_replace('~\b('. $search.')\b~', $replace, $tempString);
```

Error Details

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  preg_replace(): 
Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at 
offset 3 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Comment: You should consider using `str_replace` if you need to check for a fixed string.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a reserved preg operator, as such it should be properly escaped if it is part of the mask.

```
$search=preg_quote('+5DR');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php